# CSS doesn't allow for scrolling

Tags: css, scroll

In its current form, the CSS below doesn't allow my page to scroll. However, if I disable the CSS code below, the page allows for scrolling. I have tried setting the `overflow` attribute over and over, and using `height: 130%` allows me to see a scroll bar, but the page still doesn't actually scroll.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UDFrA/) showing my problem.

```
h1{
color: #FFF;
}

h3{
font-size: 25px;
    color: #990000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Chivo';
}

h5 {
    color: #bb0000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Chivo';
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;

    }

h5:focus {
    outline: thin dotted rgb(51, 51, 51);
        outline-width: thin;
        outline-style: dotted;
        outline-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    outline-offset: -2px;
}

h5:hover, a:active {
text-decoration: underline;
color: #990000;
outline: 0;
outline-color: initial;
outline-style: initial;
outline-width: 0px;
}

/*box!*/

#boxdrop{
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px grey;
position:fixed;
background-attachment:scroll;
left:10px;
}
#boxdrop2{box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px grey;}

.boxbg { background-color:#ccc;background-attachment:scroll; }
.boxbg2 { background-color:#ddd; background-attachment:scroll;}
.boxbg3 { background-color:#eee;background-attachment:scroll;}
.all-round {
border-radius:1em;
-moz-border-radius:1em;
-webkit-border-radius:1em;
}
```

Comment: provide a jsfiddle ad more details

Comment: @Floradu88 i have no more details to give i am really stuck

Comment: Which element(s) do you want to scroll, and in which direction?

Comment: Your HTML is a disaster. You have improperly nested, extra, and missing tags galore. Please run it through a validator before asking for help.

Comment: what tags? i removed some because jsfiddle asked to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to get the scroll back, remove the `position:fixed` from your boxdrop div.

```
#boxdrop{
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px grey;
background-attachment:scroll;
left:10px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UDFrA/1/)**

Comment: thanks it is the closest to what i want that i have gotten so far, but if i use that code the page expand in the full width of the screen

Comment: You should be able to set a `max-width` on boxdrop if you want to restrict the width.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is your HTML. You have two `div`s with the id `boxdrop2`. Also, your `div` with id `boxdrop` has a `position:fixed` attribute, so the `div` is not able to scroll in any way. Whenever you use fixed, you eliminate any chance of scrolling as the fixed elements leave the flow of elements in the page.

Comment: the 2 divs are on purpose the make the rounded rectangle

Comment: In that case, please use a `class`. Ids are only meant for use with 1 element. Also, you can use the new `border-radius` attribute in CSS3 for making rounded rectangles. (See http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_borders.asp for more information.)